# Get count by column values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  month create_time request_id weekday
1     4  2014-04-25    3647895  Friday
2    12  2013-12-06    2229374  Friday
3     4  2014-04-18    3568796  Friday
4     4  2014-04-18    3564933  Friday
5     3  2014-03-07    3081503  Friday
6     4  2014-04-18    3568889  Friday
```

And I'd like to get the count of request_ids by the weekday. How would I do this in R?

I've tried a lot of stuff based on ddply and aggregate with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(request_id ~ weekday, FUN=length, dat=df)
  weekday request_id
1  Friday          6
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several valid ways to do it.  I usually go with my trusty `sqldf()`.  If the dataframe is named D, then

```
library(sqldf)
counts <- sqldf('select weekday, count(request_id) as nrequests from D group by weekday')
```

`sqldf()` can be wordy, but it is just so easy to remember and get right the first time!

Answer (score 1):

or ... u could try:

```
count(df,"weekday")
```

or

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(weekday),summarise,count=length(month))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a `table` and take the `rowSums`

```
> rowSums(with(dat, table(weekday, request_id)))
Friday 
     6
```